# Python. Ошибка при запуске скомпилированного приложения на Windows

Tags: python, python-3.10

вчера столкнулся с такой проблемой, когда тестировал приложение **Python** в скомпилированном виде при помощи модуля Nuitka на виртуальной машине Windows 7.

При открытии приложения появлялось диалоговое окно с ошибкой : ***Запуск программы невозможен, так как на компьютере отсутствует python310.dll. Попробуйте переустановить программу.***

Такая же ошибка появлялась и после переустановки программы. Возможно ли внести какие-либо коррективы в код, чтобы программа не выдавала ошибки?

Также хотелось бы отметить, что такая же ошибка возникает даже, если программа будет скомпилирована при помощи **PyInstaller**.

Comment: Обычно, если отсутствует библиотека python*.dll, можно взять ее из папки Python и положить рядом с exe файлом. Но в данном случае все равно не поможет, т.к. Python3.10 действительно не поддерживает Win7. Можно взять более старую версию Python.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ошибка в том что в windows 7 не поддерживается python 3.9+

Comment: А это возможно как-то исправить?

Comment: Ну можно скчать windows 8+